# how do I import css file from node modules in svelte?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, svelte-3

I tried many ways to import the css file from easyMDE module, but it still was blocked or cancelled as it is shown in the image:

[image]

When i clicked on them,this was written:

> Referrer Policy: same-origin

I tried using 'rollup-plugin-css-only', adding it inside the `<head>` using `<link>` in the index.html file, but none of them worked. Could someone tell me how dould i import the css without it being bloecked?

Answer (score 0):

You've blocked the css yourself with the [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) you've put on the html.

Look for `"Content-Security-Policy"` meta tag or http header and remove it.
(Or tweak the rules to add exceptions for the css your using)